# useEffect is not triggering after routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-router

I am very new when it comes to using react hooks, rendering, and routing.

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );  
}
```

Navbar.js

```
export default function Navbar() {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path = '/:page' element = {<Header/>} />
                <Route path='/' element={<Header/>} />

                <Route exact path='' element = {<Home/>}/>
                <Route exact path='home' element = {<Home/>}/>
                <Route exact path='players' element = {<BasicTable/>}/>
                <Route exact path='about' element = {<About/>}/>
                <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

BasicTable.js

```
const getObj = async () => {
    const value = await axios.get(...);
    return value;
}

export function BasicTable(){
    const [obj, setObj] = useState();

    console.log("getting object");
    useEffect (()=> {
        console.log("using Effect");
        setObj(getObj());
    }, []);

    //Rest of the code below this...
}
```

I am trying to get the axios get call to trigger everytime someone navigates to the basic table page (/players page). If I just insert the axios.get call naked into the basic table function, this causes an infinite loop of api get calls. Now I am using the useEffect hook, but it never triggers when I navigate to "/players". In fact, it never triggers. The only thing I see is the "getting objects" console log, but never "using Effect". Am I missing an important part of useEffect?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete `BasicTable` component example? The `useEffect` hook needs to wait for the `getObj` function to resolve also.

Comment: Which router library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook is updating the `obj` state to the implicitly returned Promise object with `setObj(getObj());`. At a minimum, the `useEffect` hook needs to wait for the `getObj` function to resolve. This can be done in a couple of ways:

```
const getObj = async () => {
  const value = await axios.get(...);
  return value;
}
```

Using `async/await`:

```
export function BasicTable(){
  const [obj, setObj] = useState();

  console.log("getting object");
  useEffect (()=> {
    console.log("using Effect");

    const getObject = async () => {
      const obj = await getObj();
      setObj(obj);
    }
    
    getObject();
  }, []);

  // Rest of the code below this...
}
```

[image: Edit useeffect-is-not-triggering-after-routing]

Using Promise chain:

```
export function BasicTable(){
  const [obj, setObj] = useState();

  console.log("getting object");
  useEffect (()=> {
    console.log("using Effect");
    
    getObj().then(obj => setObj(obj));
  }, []);

  // Rest of the code below this...
}
```

In fact, because `getObj` implicitly returns a Promise object, you can simply return the Promise from `axios`.

```
const getObj = () => {
  return axios.get(...);
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that the axios is still not doing the get call because the useEffect hook does not go off. Correct me if I'm wrong but I assumed that the useEffect hook triggers when the page renders (or when the user goes onto the /player page). I tried your suggestions but the same problem remains. I originally thought it was just waiting for the api get call, but my backend is not receiving any calls.

Comment: @StantonZeng With an empty dependency array the `useEffect` hook's callback is called once after mounting at the end of the initial render. When do you want the effect to be triggered?

Comment: On the navbar the user can route themselves to the basicTable component using react-router. When they get routed to the new page, that is when I want the useEffect to to be called. I'm guessing the initial render is not ending, there is no initial render, or I am missing something completely obvious. I'll try to do more research about how useEffect and react-router works with each other.

Comment: @StantonZeng Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-is-not-triggering-after-routing-b0vk2j) demo that appears to work without issue. The `useEffect` hook callback is run upon navigating to the `"/players"` path and `BasicTable` is mounted.

Comment: That is strange that it works here. I will fiddle around with this and hopefully I'll get an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Drew is indeed correct, the issue is not with the useEffect firing, but a mishandling of the promise.  The network is still being made but your state is getting set to a `Promise {<pending>}` object, and it doesn't wait for the promise to resolve.